# Poured water into Pre-ground coffee funnel – De'Longhi Magnifica S

Tags: coffee-machines

accidentally I poured water into the duct where pre-ground coffee goes. I unplugged the machine from electricity and cleaned the inner parts according to the manual. I don't see any obvious damage, but did not try to use the machine again.

Is there anything else I should do or check before using the machine again?

Instruction manual: https://www.delonghi.com/de-de/manuals/ecam22-110-b-magnifica-s-kaffeevollautomat/p/ECAM22.110.B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with anything electronic, it should be allowed to dry thoroughly before introducing power again. With any luck the water did not cause any short circuits or damage any parts.

But there may be little to worry about here since the funnel leads to the brewing chamber which is designed to hold water. It appears that this funnel is only supposed to be use when the machine is in *scooped mode* indicated by the dial. But the dial position presumably only affects the operating programme, it doesn't align the chute or open a door or anything.

For this machine, water goes in the reservoir which is removed by pulling it forward from the right hand side facing the machine.

Comment: Thank you very much! After building the machine apart as far as described in the manual, I dried the components as far as I could, and I have let it dry for two days. The water did not go into the water reservoir, though, but behind it. Then, presumably the water left the machine at the bottom quickly. The machine is making coffee as before now!